# Поменять переменные местами

Tags: delphi, указатели, delphi-7

Известная задача, но вот интересен вопрос, как сделать такое на `Delphi` в виде функции для переменных любого типа данных (возможно, за исключением объектов). Что-то вроде такого?

```
procedure swap(a, b: pointer);
var c: pointer;
begin
    c^ := a^;
    a^ := b^;
    b^ := c^;
end;
```

Будет работать?

Comment: нет, не будет - попробуйте

Comment: @Igor, нет возможности попробовать, к сожалению, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: В D7 для простых типов можно через Variant сделать, в более поздних версиях через дженерики, а для сложных типов универсально не сделаете скорее всего придётся писать для каждого свой метод

Answer (score 1):

```
  TCommon = class
 ...
    class procedure Swap<T> (var X1, X2: T);
 ...
  end;


class procedure TCommon.Swap<T> (var X1, X2: T);
var X : T;
begin
  X := X2;
  X2 := X1;
  X1 := X;
end;
```

Это работает для XE2, возможно для новых компиляторов можно проще, без класса.

Comment: у вопроса метка Delphi 7. В те времена о дженериках даже не помышляли

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя абстрактный указатель разыменовать вот так. Какой тип получится? Byte .. Double .. String .. record ? Вот и компилятор без дополнительных подсказок не знает, и не выполнит.

А вам известен язык, в котором такое прокатит?

---

Вы можете обменять указатели местами, если это вам что-то даст:

```
procedure swap(var a, b: pointer); // Добавляем var
var c: pointer;
begin
    c := a;
    a := b;
    b := c;
end;
```

Comment: например, в PHP, JS можно реализовать функцию, меняющую местами 2 переменные независимо от типа, потому что там нет жесткой привязки к типам. Просто интересовал вопрос, можно ли такое реализовать на Delphi.

Comment: Я имел ввиду именно указатели. В JS их, насколько я знаю, нет.